# Debugging/Testing stripe webhook calls to Laravel Spark

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, webhooks, laravel-spark, laravel-cashier

I am currently testing Stripe webhooks using the latest Laravel Spark. I've got a Stripe account working, meaning that I can add (fake) creditcards and charge subscriptions/single payments. Next, I am using a fake hook endpoint (ultrahook.com) to retrieve webhooks requests from Stripe.

My vanilla route file is from the Spark installation:

```
$router->post('/webhook/stripe', 'Settings\Billing\StripeWebhookController@handleWebhook');
```

And should handle all the webhooks fine. To test the webhooks, I checked the StripeWebhookController object and changed a method to log some info:

```
protected function handleInvoicePaymentSucceeded(array $payload)
{

  Log::info('This is some useful handleInvoicePaymentSucceeded.');
}
```

However, nothing gets logged when I call run a Stripe test webhook of type: invoice.payment_succeeded.

I do see the request coming into the ultrahook console and it gets returned a 200. I can also copy paste the JSON Stripe test webhook and paste it into Postman after which it gets send to http://localhost:80/webhook/stripe ... again a 200 response but nothing logged.

Any advice?

Answer (score 3):

Laravel Cashier instructs you to exclude the webhook routes from `VerifyCsrfToken` middleware as stated here:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/billing#handling-stripe-webhooks

Spark uses Cashier, I'd imagine you need to do the same then.

Comment: Thanks BTL, I expected it to be set already by Spark since it is something that should work out of the box but it wasn't set. I think the route is listed outside of the web middleware group. Anyone, I added it anyway and it didn't do anything...

Answer (score 2):

Well, it appears that I needed to add

CASHIER_ENV=testing

in the env file. Nice to see that in the documentation Laravel... not

Answer (score 1):

stripe webhooks don't call localhost, it should have a domain name to call.

you may use ultrahook gem for that..

it will create a temporary binding url which you can provide in stripe dashboard as callback url

like this

```
ultrahook stripe 80
```

which would give you an url that you map it in stripe dashboard

```
http://stripe.somename.ultrahook.com -> http://localhost:80
```

NOTE: You can access this url on a browser, it is just a virtual binding

Comment: Yes I was using Ultrahook for local testing.